# Damped Wave Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

I understand what the general solution is to a wave equation, but am unsure of the general solution for a damped wave equation.  If someone knows what that is, or the steps to find it, that would be greatly appreciated. I can give the rest of the problem if needed but I think the part that matters for the general solution is:

$$U_t+U_{tt} = U_{xx}, \;\; 0 < x < 4, 0 < t < \infty$$

Comment: I edited your question to $\LaTeX$ify it!  Cheers!

Comment: Also added the pde tag.

Comment: Separation of variables probably will work well. Laplace Transforming time. Do you have boundary conditions specified?

Comment: It strikes me that you may have intended to write $0 \le x \le 4$ instead of $0 < x < 4$, and $0 \le t < \infty$ instead of $0 < t < \infty$.  Do you see why?  Any thoughts/comments on these remarks?  Cheers!

Comment: It might in fact be a good idea if you did give "the rest of the problem".  For instance, are you looking for the standard "vibrating string" solutions with $x(0)  = x(4) = 0$?  It seems to me you might well be.  I'm working on an answer and such details would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me, but in my last comment I meant to type $U(0) = U(4) = 0$, and not $x(0) = x(4)  = 0$.   Sorry if I caused any confusion.

Comment: I also added the mathematical physics tag, for reasons which should become clear when my answer is posted; soon, I hope.

Comment: I've decided to upvote, but please consider adding some of your work to the post. Perhaps the undamped wave can still be separated? (Just a guess)

Answer (score 2):

This PDE is separable as written. Assume solutions of the form $U(x,t)=X(x)\cdot T(t)$
$$U_{tt}+U_t=U_{xx}$$ $$XT''+XT'=X''T$$ $$\frac{T''}{T}+\frac{T'}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda$$
The equation separates into $$T''+T'+\lambda T=0 \mbox{ and } X''+\lambda X = 0$$
The solution to the first equation is the span of $$\left\{e^{-t/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{4\lambda -1}}{2} t\right) \ ,\ e^{-t/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{4\lambda -1}}{2} t\right)\right\}$$
and the solution to the second equation is the span of $$\{\cos\left(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot x\right)\ ,\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot x\right)\}$$
Thus, the general solution consists of linear combinations of products of these sets, with appropriate values for $\lambda$. If we choose to impose 0-Dirichlet boundary condition $X(0)=X(4)=0$, then the spatial solution reduces to the sine function, and the appropriate values for $\lambda$ are $\sqrt{\lambda_n}=\frac{n\pi}{4}$ for positive integers $n$.
This yields a solution of the form: $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n e^{-t/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2\pi^2/4-1}}{2} t\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{4}\right)+b_n e^{-t/2}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2\pi^2/4-1}}{2} t\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{4}\right)$$
for indexed constants $a_n, b_n$. The constants $a_n$ are the Fourier sine coefficients for an imposed initial condition $U(x,0)=f(x)$. The constants $b_n$ are rescaled to produce the Fourier sine coefficients of an imposed initial velocity $U_t(x,0)=g(x)$.

For example, a fundamental mode $u(x,0)=\sin(\frac{\pi x}{4})$ with $u_t(x,0)=0$

[image: Damped Wave]